# Open in new tab takes the session from the main window

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, tabs

I have this strange problem that is driving me crazy.

I have a ASP.NET web application that is hosted on Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.

It uses Windows Authentication and Digest.

Now, the application runs fine. When the user opens the app the first time, he is prompted for the username and password. And then he logs in fine.

the problem is:

there is a page inside the application where the user will click a link and this link will target a Blank window (tab) in IE11. this new page will show some report. The user is supposed to view the report and then close the tab and continue working on the application. However, when the user closes this tab and try to use the web application, he is being prompted to enter the username and password again!

I tried something, on the new tab, i just modify the URL to navigate to the home page... it works fine from the tab.

as if this new tab got hold of the session that the user is on! and when you close the tab, you close the session with it.

how is that possible? and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't have any `Session.Abandon` actions or similar in your code?

Comment: no .. i don't use that

Comment: Session timeout for long report build?
Any error in the blank page that cause app pool recycling?

Comment: nope .. like i said .. it all happens only when i open the new tab .. the session moves to the new tab. when the new tab is closed .. the main tab will ask me for password if i try to do any action on it. it happens instantly actually ..